# Update the oldest record where an overlap exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, common-table-expression, overlap

I have a lot of inaccurate records; the analyst uploaded data without processing so in this db I have a lot of overlapped dates between rows in `INI` and `FIN`, for example:

```
valido ID  id_tip id_hr  perpro    rut         ini                      fin                     ult_act
------ --- ------ ----- --------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------
1      52   001    666   201802    6666666-6   2018-05-01 00:00:00.000 2018-05-10 00:00:00.000 2018-09-12 00:00:00.000
1      53   001    666   201802    6666666-6   2018-05-09 00:00:00.000 2018-05-12 00:00:00.000 2018-09-13 00:00:00.000
```

For that I want to create a CTE/Stored Procedure that displays **both records**: the one that is overlapped and the one it overlaps with. Then update the oldest based on `ULT_ACT` which is a timestamp for when it was uploaded. My current select is able to print the older record that gets overlapped with the new one and the ones that have matching `INI2` and `FIN1` dates:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_HR ORDER BY ULT_ACT ASC) AS IDOR, 
T.ID, 
T.RUT, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,T.INI,112) AS INI,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,T.FIN,112) AS FIN, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,T.ULT_ACT,112) AS ULT_ACT
FROM TSTSOLAP t 
WHERE EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM TSTSOLAP T2 
        WHERE t.RUT = t2.RUT AND
            T.ID_TIP = T2.ID_TIP AND
            T.ID <> t2.ID AND 
            (T2.INI BETWEEN T.INI AND T.FIN)
            OR T2.INI = T.FIN
            --T2.INI < T.FIN OR
            --T2.INI = T.FIN
            --OR t.INI <= t2.FIN
    )
ORDER BY ID
--UPDATE I WANT TO IMPLEMENT, IT CHANGES FIN AND SETS IT TO T2.INI - 1 SO IT REMOVES THE OVERLAPPED CONDITION
--UPDATE TSTSOLAP SET T.FIN=INI-1 WHERE IDOR > 1
```

Which prints this:

```
valido ID  id_tip id_hr  perpro    rut         ini                      fin                     ult_act
------ --- ------ ----- --------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------
1      52   001    666   201802    6666666-6   2018-05-01 00:00:00.000 2018-05-10 00:00:00.000 2018-09-12 00:00:00.000
```

I would like help on printing both cases and the update implementation in a more "executable" way.

Comment: Unless I miss the point, I don't see an overlap in your example. The `fin` of the first record precedes the `ini` of the next.

Comment: My bad, I tiped from the phone.

Comment: What is an example of your desired result, based on the sample data in your question?